Understanding 技術・技能を活かした各職業というものがございます
From Konosuba chapter 1, a merchant seems explains to Kazuma that a job 冒険者 is an umbrella term for many kinds of jobs:

冒険者とはいわゆる総称で、技術・技能を活かした各職業というものがございます。

I wonder why 活かした is in past tense? Why it is not 活かす instead? Also, what is the role of というもの? It looks redundant to me.


～というもの is "something called ～". It's optional, but it clearly indicates you're introducing a new concept to the listener, which is often helpful.
Regarding 活かした, please read: Could someone please explain the meaning of 場面に合った? In this case, saying "技術・技能を活かす各職業" also makes perfect sense, but I feel saying 活かした仕事 focuses on how those jobs were established as a result of people utilizing their skills.

